# Search function - Linked List

Tags: c++, list, function, search

I am working on a search function to search a linked list for a specific value. When it finds that value I want to output its position. I cannot seem to get past the first node without getting an error. I think something is wrong with the loops but I'm not sure what.

```
int NumberList::search(double num)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr;
    nodePtr=head;
    int i=0;
    while (nodePtr->value!= NULL)
    {
        i=i+1;
        if (nodePtr->value==num)
            return i;
        else
            nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What if `nodePtr` is `NULL`?!

Comment: you should say what error you are getting

Comment: Post a [MCVE] when asking for this kind of error diagnosis here please. Otherwise your question is off-topic.

Comment: Never use `==` and `!=` to compare floating point numbers. http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is incorect.  You should be testing that `nodePtr` is not `NULL`

```
while (nodePtr != NULL)
{
    i = i + 1;
    if (nodePtr->value == num)
        return i;
    else
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}
```

Also this is a perfect reason to use [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead of `NULL` when dealing with pointers.  If you had use `nullptr` then

```
while (nodePtr->value!= nullptr)
```

Would give you a compiler error as you cannot compare a `double` to `nullptr`

Comment: nodePtr could be a sentinel node where nodePtr->value == NULL

Comment: thank you!! this helped! i had to fix this and something else in my class.

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes but since the OP is comparing `value` to `num` I am assuming `value` is a non pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how the corresponding class is defined but I think in any case the function should look the following way

```
int NumberList::search(double num)
{
    ListNode *nodePtr = head;
    int i = 0;

    while ( nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != num )
    {
        ++i;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next
    }

    return nodePtr != NULL ? ++i : 0;
}
```

It is difficult to compare exactly two floating numbers. You should use a method of comparison that for example takes into account an epsilon.

Take also into account that other functions as for example the function that adds nodes to the list can also be wrong.:)

Comment: hint#1: `num` is `double`. hint#2: comparing floating point...

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский I appended my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop condition should be:

```
while (nodePtr != NULL)
```

Because of this error you are likely visiting a node who's pointer is `NULL` And by dereferencing this you are causing *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the `ListNode` type but I'm guessing the `value` is a `double`.

> `while (nodePtr->value != NULL)`

Here you're checking if the `double` is not `NULL` (`NULL` is essentially `0`). But you need to test `nodePtr` against `NULL`.

**Note:** Consider using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, `nullptr` is the type safe value for a null pointer and would have produced a compilation error.

> error: invalid operands of types 'double' and 'std::nullptr_t' to binary 'operator=='